# getting next 5 years for all projects in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I need next 5 years for all projects
As an example: Let's say project number is 1 and start year for that project is 2015 then I need next 5 year for that project. Just like that for another project number 2 if start year is 2018 then I need next 5 years from 2018.

Expected Output:

```
Project number   Year

1----------------2015

1------------------2016

1------------------2017

1-----------------2018

1------------------2019

2------------------2018

2------------------2019

2------------------2020

2-------------------2021

2-----------------2022
```

Here is the code that I have written but it is not giving me anything that I expected.

```
WITH YEARLIST
AS (SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER
            ,START_YEAR AS YEAR
    FROM TABLE_ABC

    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
            PROJECT_NUMBER
            ,Y.YEAR +1 AS YEAR
            FROM YEARLIST Y
            WHERE Y.YEAR >= Y.YEAR +5
    )
    SELECT 
        PROJECT_NUMBER
        ,YEAR
    FROM YEARLIST

    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you please provide your current output?

Comment: Are you trying to use a loop?

Comment: It is just only showing the start year for project @Mitrucho

Comment: Yes I am using recursive CTE....and wants to limit record for next 5 years for particular project. But if anyone can suggest me some way with the use of while loop. Then I can proceed on that as well @Wes Palmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the formatting, I'm new to the site.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP1(PrId SMALLINT, StrtYr SMALLINT)

INSERT INTO #TMP1  (PrId,StrtYr)
VALUES
(1,2015),
(2,2018),
(3,2016),
(4,2014),
(5,2017),
(6,2015)



SELECT 
    * 
FROM #TMP1
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (StrtYr + 1)
                                ,(StrtYr + 2)
                                ,(StrtYr + 3)
                                ,(StrtYr + 4)
                                ,(StrtYr + 5)
                                ) FutureYear(futureyear)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte
as
(
select 1 as id,2015 as year,2015+5 as baseyear
union all
select id,year+1,baseyear from cte c
where c.year<baseyear
)
select * from cte
```

This condition `Y.YEAR >= Y.YEAR +5` will execute only once..so your code goes like this

```
WITH YEARLIST
AS (
SELECT PROJECT_NUMBER
      ,START_YEAR AS YEAR
      ,START_YEAR+5 as BaseYear
    FROM TABLE_ABC

    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
            PROJECT_NUMBER
            ,Y.YEAR +1 AS YEAR,
            BaseYear
            FROM YEARLIST Y
            WHERE Y.YEAR < Y.BaseYear
    )
    SELECT 
        PROJECT_NUMBER
        ,YEAR
    FROM YEARLIST
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing where you want to use a numbers or tally table. This is the swiss army knife of t-sql. I keep mine in a view like this.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Next we need to setup a test table and some sample data.

```
create table #Projects
(
    ProjectNumber int
    , StartYear int 
)

insert #Projects (ProjectNumber, StartYear)
values (1, 2015),(2, 2018)
```

Now that we have everything established it is a simple query to retrieve the desired output using our tally table.

```
select ProjectNumber
    , OutputYear = datepart(year, DATEADD(year, x.N - 1, convert(char(4), StartYear) + '-01-01'))
from #Projects p
cross apply 
(
    select N
    from cteTally t
    where t.N <= 5
) x
order by p.ProjectNumber
    , OutputYear
```

I used this tally table cte instead of your recursive one because when we use a recursive cte for counting it is really a loop behind the scenes and not a good practice. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: Thanks @Sean Lange.. I tried this one and it gives me a perfect result...But pacreely 's logic is simple.So, I am using that one. Thanks for your answer. I will use this logic in future...